# Can an employer retroactively change my start date so my tax and NI deductions are correct?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, start-date

I worked in March for a small family-run company getting cash in hand. Only in April was I made an official employee and given proper pay cheques where my PAYE taxes and NI are deducted.

I checked my HMRC account online and it says my start date for the company was in April and not March.

I need to fill in my self-assessment tax return and want to declare all the cash I earned in March. However as this is before my ‘official’ start date I’m worried this is going to cause problems.

Can my employer (who I care about) fix this retrospectively? I won’t even need to pay the tax on the money for 2022-2023 because I was unemployed for a lot of the year, however, I still want to do everything honestly and correctly.

Comment: Even if you were paid in cash, you are still responsible to pay the taxes on that income.  You will be responsible for deducting the taxes from that income yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You - and your employer - need to take proper advice from an expert, not random people on the internet. Phoning HMRC may get you that advice, though it might also cause them to look more closely at your employer's practices than they are comfortable with if they make a habit of paying cash-in-hand. Maybe this can be treated as an oversight by the employer and fixed retrospectively. Maybe you can treat that month as having been self-employed. It's a lot more straightforward to do this honestly and correctly if the employer also does/has. Start by speaking to your employer, and then contact HMRC if you need to clarify whether/how you can declare this as self-employed income.

Answer (score 9):

Possible but probably unwise.

If your employer registered a correction with HMRC, giving an earlier start date, they would then be liable for back payments of employer's NI and pension contributions.  These would be a greater sum than your employee contributions.  They may not like that.  It may even affect their mandatory filings with Companies House.

I would suggest you declare the earlier work as casual labour.  You can always get advice directly from HMRC for this issue, which may be the wisest action of all.

Answer (score 4):

If you were getting 'cash in hand' meaning the employer wasn't deducting tax and NI, then in effect you would be self employed/contractor. Why not just enter the figures you earned in cash on your self assessment and pay the tax according.